SSH tunelling setup to access a database in a container
I have a Mariadb database running in a container, running in a server machine (let's call its IP address "DB")
In another server (let's call its IP address "APP"), an application is running within another container. This application needs to access the database, but I would like to do this via a SSH tunnel, instead of the 3306 port.
I am not familiar with tunnelling, so, from a shell in the container running on the APP machine, I tried:
ssh -f user@DB -L 1234:127.0.0.1:3306 -N -p 5678 -4
(5678 is the SSH port of the DB machine, I can successfully ssh to this machine on this port. And the tunnel is apparently successfully established)
Then I try:
mariadb -h localhost -P 1234 -u dbuser -p
But I get this error:
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 11
However, connecting directly to the database works fine:
mariadb -h DB -u dbuser -p
Can you please help me fixing this?
And is tunnelling as I try to do, a proper approach to secure the access to the database?
Additional info: on the DB machine, the 3306 port of the database container is mapped with:
docker run -v [DB]:3306:3306 ...
Many thanks!

You establish the tunnel on Machine A to connect to Machine B. Then on Machine A you run your mariadb -h localhost -P 1234 -u dbuser -p command, not in the shell that was opened up for the SSH command. (just confirming that was the step you took).

Take a look at ss -nl output on remote machine and look at the interfaces that the container is listening on. Something is odd, but its also definitely not a programming question - recommend serverfault

Thanks for suggesting serverfault, and for this ss command I did not know!

I have found the issue: the -v option for docker run was incorrect: it had to be 127.0.0.1 instead of [DB], in order to let the host access the 3306 port of its hosted container.
